# what payment gateway should i use in django

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

**hi i am new to django maybe few months ago,but successfully created a website but it needed a**

- *payment Gateway*

**now i want to ask is their any**

- **third party used for payment in django*
- *built in django-payment gateway*
- *or how do i go about the payment method**

**i have tried using**

- *Stripe but its does not work for my country because its not in the list of countries its working with*

**Note**= *if their is any tutorial i can follow with any recommended payment gateway, kindly provide*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

django payment is what i used and its more easier https://django-payments.readthedocs.io/en/latest/